# Extracting/updatating hibernate string parameter values in where clause

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, orm

I want to apply some sort of String formatting for all values passed to a query in `where` clause conditions. So I need a common place (interceptor, event handler,..) where I can catch/update where parameter values for applying the string common formatting.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no such thing to intercept parameter binding, other than providing your own [Hibernate Custom Type](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/types.html#types-custom).